# How to make a press on a button in ReplyKeyboardMarkup not to send a message (python-telegram-bot)

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, phone-number, python-telegram-bot

I have to ask user for his phone number, so I made a custom ReplyKeyboardMarkup with digits to make it easier for user to reply. But whenever user presses a digit, it automatically sends a message containing this digit. How to disable this feature (or are there other ways like call system keyboard with digits already)?
I have this code:

```
keyboard = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9'], ['+', '0', ' ']]
update.message.reply_text(
    'Enter your phone:',
    reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=keyboard)
)
```

P.S. I am already using request_contact as one of the possibilities.

UPD: I haven't found any bots that implement that, so it can be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [inline keyboards buttons](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton), or ask the phone number of user by setting `request_contact` field on "true" in [Keyboard Button](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) object.

Comment: To use InlineKeyboardMarkup is a solution, but I think the idea of inline keyboards is a bit different. Anyway, thank you.